# Angular 1.5 - Component() Method

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the component method working which is new for Angular 1.5. So far I acheived the following see my jsFiddle [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/t088vLdp/). For some reason I can not get the templateUrl working so that I can see the html template with the defined scope. Any help would be great.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/t088vLdp/)
**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.name = "Tony Danza";


});

app.component("myBox",  {
      bindings: {},
      controller: function($element) {
        var myBox = this;
        myBox.game = 'World Of warcraft';
      },
      controllerAs: 'myBox',
      templateUrl: "/template",
      transclude: true
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/template">
    <div style='width:40%;border:2px solid black;background-color:yellow'>
      Your Favourite game is: {{myBox.game}}
    </div>
  </script>



  Hi {{name}}
  <div my-box>
  </div my-box>

</div><!--end app-->
```

Comment: Components must be elements. Use `<my-box>` instead of `<div my-box>`

Comment: See [DEMO in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bexuczxs/)

Comment: From the Docs: "Such components are always isolated (i.e. `scope: {}`) and are always restricted to elements (i.e. `restrict: 'E'`). [AngularJS $compileProvider API Reference -- component](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider)

Comment: Thanks so simple, it all works now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular components must be elements.  Use `<my-box>` instead of `<div my-box>`.

[The documentation on Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) doesn't make this immediately clear, but it is documented.

> when you want a directive that is triggered by an attribute or CSS class, rather than an element

[The directive/component comparison table](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#comparison-between-directive-definition-and-component-definition) also explains that `restrict` is unavailable for components and they are always elements.

Comment: I am wondering the purpose of $ element in the components controller?  Since the components are not meant for manipulating the dom, and we are still to use the link function that exists in the directives syntax.

Comment: @explosion pills can u plz help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252729/have-a-common-component-across-all-component-with-angular-1-5-component