# how to set header for each page using component in Angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, angularjs-components

I started with Angular 1.5 component recently.
I am having various pages in my application. So I decided to create a `<my-title>` component which am using inside `<my-header>` component. 
As you see in navbar I have First, Second as navigation links. In my application there will be more parent child combinations.

I want to set title of each page by two way.

1. By giving it in partial `<my-title>Home</my-title>` (see 1.html or 2.html)
   (Manuel's answer satisfies this Scenario)
2. Also I would like to set it from controller as well. `vm.title = "current page title"` (Accepted Answer Satisfies This Scenario Only)

**I think any one thing can be done from above two options. There are two answers by different person for option 1(Deblaton) and option 2(Manuel). Both answers satisfies respective scenarios. I accepted who answered first correctly.**

Updated: If you see file "1.html" on plunker. I am trying to set `<my-title> First page</my-title>`. but that is not working. My key idea is that developer will give `<my-title>Current Page Title</my-title>` on partial and it will be shown as per current page when he navigates across.

Please keep in mind I will be exposing only `<my-title>` to partial and controller.
 `<my-header>` will be at one place only. Only Title will be changed.
If there are some new pages navigation links will be added to `<my-header>`.

There is lot of code to copy-paste here. Please visit this [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/zTLRSggDaCq8eraafRoK?p=preview).

```
module.component('myFirstApp', {
   templateUrl: "mainview.html",
   $routeConfig: [
     {path: '/', redirectTo: ['/First'] },
     {path: '/first', name: 'First', component: 'firstComponent'},
     {path: '/second', name: 'Second', component: 'secondComponent'}
   ]
 })

 module.component('firstComponent', {
   templateUrl: "1.html"
 });

 module.component('secondComponent', {
   templateUrl: "2.html"
 });

 module.component('myTitle', {
   template: '<h1>{{model.title}}</h1>'
 });

 module.component('myHeader', {
   templateUrl: "my-header.html"
 });
```

[image]

Comment: want to set "title" either from partial or from controller.

Comment: If you see file "1.html" on plunker. I am trying to set <my-title>First page</my-title>.  but that is not working. My key idea is that developer will give <my-title>Current Page Title</my-title> on partial and it will be shown.

Comment: okay.  Updated :) Although I already mentioned am trying to expose <my-title> by two way.

Comment: I don't see anywere toi be defined the controller and to have it referrenced for your components. Please update the code to include this too.

Comment: @diana didn't get u, can u elaborate

Comment: Well any angularjs page has an app (module), then it must have a controller, and then each component should have its own controller - this is the place you have the business logic related to each component/directive.

Comment: @diana done that, can u have a look and answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, using component routing, it looks like a good idea to use a controller for handling your title. (with ui-router, I would have used the resolve option).

I decided to inject $rootScope, and use it for sharing title value. You can also do it with a service.

so, the component :

```
module.component('firstComponent', {
  templateUrl: "1.html",
  controller: ["$rootScope", function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.appVars = $rootScope.appVars || {};
    $rootScope.appVars.title = "Title from Page 1";
  }]
});
```

and the directive :

```
module.component('myTitle', {
  template: '<h1>{{$root.appVars.title}}</h1>'
});
```

Here is your updated plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/6PCfznxsJzCPQtBm2oyN?p=preview

Comment: It works like a champ. Able to set title from controller. 
Just a simple query why it is {{$root.title}} in template. Just curious to know what is going behind the scene.
Any idea how to make <my-title> I am Page one <my-title> work, that will complete the answer. :)

Comment: @ankitdadhich With the "controller As" syntax, everything that is inside `$rootScope` is accessible in all templates using `$root`.

Comment: @ankitdadhich I don't see what's missing inside your `myTitle` directive

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a couple of things in your code.

1. You need to use bindings in order to pass parameters to components
2. You are using the word "model" in your templates to refer to model, but that's not the default one to do that. In here you can do 2 things, you can use $ctrl in templates or define controllerAs in component.

Component example:

```
module.component('myTitle', {
  template: '<h1>{{model.title}}</h1>',
  controllerAs: 'model',
  bindings: {
    title: '<'
  }
});
```

Use example:

```
<my-title title="'I am First'"></my-title>
```

Note the quotation marks inside the double quotation marks in "'I am First'".
You need both because you are passing a string as parameter.

In order to change the title in the header I created a service to allow the communication from components under *ng-outlet* and outer components because you can not pass data as bindings via routes.

Your Plunker with the changes: https://plnkr.co/edit/ScpJYQItsMQlyd1Eacyi?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @gyc, I've updated his plunker and edited the answer with the link.

Comment: but you see it doesn't do what he wants. The header title doesn't change.

Comment: I've completed the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ScpJYQItsMQlyd1Eacyi?p=preview) to change the title in the header when navigating